# Create a trigger to run before TRUNCATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I use a MySQL trigger before `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

I have Googled it but I can't find any answers.

P.S. I made the trigger before `DELETE` but when I run `TRUNCATE TABLE xxx`, the trigger doesn't start; it starts only when I use `DELETE` in a query, not `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: Did you tried reading document? Triggers applies only for DML and not for DDL.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry my friend but I have no idea what are DML ans DDL.
I only want to insert the averrage of the table to another table before deleting all records.

Comment: In that case, consider learning basic SQL. Here is a good reading about various types of commands in SQL http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/02/sql-server-example-of-ddl-dml-dcl-and-tcl-commands/

Comment: I edited this to clarify the title and the question based on the comments, add formatting markup, and remove irrelevant tags. I'm voting to reopen this question. Although the question is answered in the documentation, it's a solid question nonetheless.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear what this is asking. Flawed assumptions or trigger firing, but pretty clear. Think we all know the answer now. Voted to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried reading the specific document? Triggers applies only for DML statements (`INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE`) and not for DDL commands (`TRUNCATE`).

Since you tagged both `MySQL` and `SQL Server`

Look at [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html); `create trigger` syntax says

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    trigger_body

Where trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Look at [SQL Server Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189799.aspx); `create trigger` syntax says

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name 
ON { table | view } 
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } 
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }
```

As you can see, `trigger` events are only `INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE`. 
It's not possible using trigger in `truncate` statement.

Comment: thanks @Rahul , i thought i can do it with a trigger....
Ill will try to find another solution for it